# NativeScript/TypeScript Sharing Cookies from HTTP/Module to Web-View on Android

Tags: java, cookies, nativescript

I use the HTTP/Module to send the authentication request to the server and it returns a set of session cookies.  On iOS these cookies are automatically shared between subsequent HTTP/Module requests and WebView requests.  I've been working on sharing cookies between the HTTP/Module and the WebView on Android.

I've built up this code to implement the transfer of cookies:

```
import application = require("application");
declare var android: any;
declare var java: any;

/** other code goes here **/

private static  syncCookies_android() {

    // // Get cookies from the URLSession 
    var javaCookieManager = java.net.CookieHandler.getDefault();
    var cookieStore = javaCookieManager.getCookieStore();
    var cookieList = cookieStore.getCookies();

    console.log("cookieList: " + cookieList);

    //Set the cookie for the web-view
    var context = application.android.context;
    var cookieSyncManager = android.webkit.CookieSyncManager.createInstance(context);
    var cookieManager = android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance();

    cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
    cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();
    for (var cookie of cookieList) {
       console.log("cookie: " + cookie);
       cookieManager.setCookie(config.apiServerURL, cookie);
    }
    cookieSyncManager.sync();

}
```

This is close, but looping through the data structure `for (var cookie of cookieList)` doesn't enumerate the items in the list.

Output:

`JS: cookieList: [CFID=9470738, CFTOKEN=22cf8b7e0e4d8778-4408CB33-C541-D779-2FECB8F2324F1CAA, MESSAGEMODE=chrono, BNI_OFPSSL=0000000000000000000000006901500a00005000]
chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(104)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0`

So I know I'm getting the data back I expect, but it doesn't seem to be in a form that acts like a javascript array.

The `console.log("cookie: " + cookie);` appears never to be called.

Comment: I've found the method `toArray()` on the return value of `getCookies()`.  This allows me to loop through the values as an array.  But my call to `setCookie` seems to be crashing the thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discovered a debugging tool  `console.dir(obj)` it is a javascript function that displays all the methods and attributes of an object.

From that I found that I needed to call the `toArray()` on my `cookieList` and `toString()` on my individual `cookie` to convert these arguments to the type required.

This code works for me:

```
private static  syncCookies_android() {

    // // Get cookies from the URLSession 
    var javaCookieManager = java.net.CookieHandler.getDefault();
    var cookieStore = javaCookieManager.getCookieStore();
    var cookieList = cookieStore.getCookies();

    //Set the cookie for the webview
    var context = application.android.context;
    var cookieSyncManager = android.webkit.CookieSyncManager.createInstance(context);
    var cookieManager = android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance();

    cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
    cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();
    for (var cookie of cookieList.toArray()) {
         cookieManager.setCookie(config.apiServerURL, cookie.toString());
    }
    cookieSyncManager.sync();
    cookieManager.flush();
}
```

Note that `config.apiServerURL` resolves to something like `http://my.server.com`